# Compositing: Mask layer opacity keyframes are not saved

Tags: compositing-nodes, keyframes, masking, saving

I am working with the node-based compositor in Blender 4.0.2.

I have a mask. The mask consists of several layers, animated to follow action in the clip. As the mask layers pass the subject, I set a keyframe on the opacity to 1. When the mask layers are no longer in use, I set a keyframe on the opacity to 0. It all works beautifully and renders as desired. The field lights up green and turns gold when it's on a keyframe as expected. The mask spline animations work perfectly.

However, when I save the composition and come back to it later, all opacity keyframes for mask layers are gone, and the field reverts to gray. It retains only the value it had when saved (inactive masks are saved with 0, active are saved with 1).

Any suggestions on how I can get my mask opacity keyframes to save?